# Load more json data in ListView

Tags: android, json, scroll, android-listview

Has anyone seen a example for android to load more `json` data as the user scrolls down the page? I have seen various example using static arrays and generating text by adding a counter to it, but I am looking for an example using `json` data so it loads a few records then when the user scrolls down it loads some more etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

Write an adapter for your list items and add a method to append new results

```
public class JsonListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private List<JSONObject> list;

   public void appendList(List<JSONObject>pList) {
       if (list== null) {
           list= new List<JSONObject>();
       }
       if (pList != null) {
           list.addAll(pList);
           notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   }
...
}
```

Add a scroll listener to start the paging request

```
private class PagingScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

    private int lastOffset = 0;


    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        boolean isEndOfListReached = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;
        boolean isOffsetRequested = lastOffset >= totalItemCount;

        if (isEndOfListReached && !isOffsetRequested) {
            lastOffset = totalItemCount;
            new PagingRequest(myListAdapter).execute(lastOffset);
        }
    }
...
}
```

Load next batch of data and update the adapter:

```
private static class PagingRequest extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<JSONObject> {

   private JsonListAdapter mAdapter;

   public PagingRequest(JsonListAdapter adapter) {
      this.mAdapter = adapter;
   }

    protected ProductList doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        int offset = params[0];
        // PERFORM REQUEST WITH OFFSET
        return newResults;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<JSONObject> result) {
        mAdapter.appendList(result);
    }
 }
```

Disclaimer: This is just the basic strategy, you still need to fill in the blanks and adapt to your code.

Comment: Thanks for that but I was looking for a complete example - i.e. a eclipse project - many claim to do this but either don't use JSON data OR do but don't implement the "load more" link at the bottom of the listview they just load all the JSON data, and if you have 10,000 rows that's a lot to swallow...